# Progress bar sincronizing in VB

Tags: vb.net, process, progress-bar

Is it possible sincronize the progress bar with the behaviour of one specific process, to have an idea of the remaning time to the end of that process?

For example I have found only this code, but it is useless because the process (that I launch with the button) finish before that the progress bar arrive to the max.

---

Button event:

```
Timer1.enabled = true
```

---

```
If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
           ProgressBar1.Value += 1
       ElseIf ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
           Timer1.Stop()
           MsgBox("finish")
       End If
```

Comment: How (or when, by what, ...) is the ProgressBar being updated? Just by the timer?

Comment: @DerMike yes, simply by the timer, it is completely disconnected from the process that I launch.

Comment: Can't the process set the progress bar? (Well, *why* does it not?)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no reasonable way to estimate how long a process will take, and it is **very** rare that you do when the process itself doesn't provide a progress indication, then you cannot reasonably display an accurate progress indication.

So don't try, set the Style property of the control to Marquee.  Make it visible when you start the process and hide it when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Using the timer is not the best solution when displaying progress. The execution time might differ from machine to machine.

You should find a way to update `ProgressBar1` from within your process.